# dropdown not reset after clicking button when using selectpicker-p

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i'm using dropdown with  class="selectpicker-p"
when using this class the dropdown will not reset

view:

```
<div class="form-group dropdown-full-width">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fullname">Emrgency:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select ng-model="urgency" ng-init="urgency='regular'" class="selectpicker-p" >
            <option  ng-repeat="urgencyItem in urgencyArray"  ng-init="urgency='regular'" value="{{urgencyItem.value}}" >{{urgencyItem.value}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="asad()">save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller :

```
$scope.asad=function(){
    $scope.urgency='Regular'
}
```

if i use the class="selectpicker-p" on select Element the dropdown  will not reset , 
otherwise if i remove it the dropdown will reset and get the default value

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: can you add jsfiddle link or explain it clearly ??

Comment: i have dropdown with  class="selectpicker-p" when i try to submit the dropdown should reset and get  the defalut value , but it not happen if i use the  class="selectpicker-p"
when i remove the class="selectpicker-p" it work fine

Comment: This might help you [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/10/)